# Getting sheet name from a cell that has data pulled from other sheet in same spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have multiple sheets in a spreadsheet. Sheet "Priority" pulls data from other sheets using "=".

Example "=Exterior!5:5" is in B2 of "Priority" sheet, pulling from "Exterior" sheet.
I want A2 on the "Priority" sheet to display the name of the sheet being used in column B. I'd like to drag down column A in "Priority" sheet and fill column A with whatever sheet is being refenced in B column.

I've tried creating a function and also tried INDIRECT. But alas I have failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() != "Sheet0" || e.range.columnStart != 2  )return;
  //e.source.toast("Gate");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const f = e.range.getFormula();
  const name = f.slice(1,f.indexOf("!"));
  e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(name);
}
```

Whenever you edit B2 with a formula like `=SheetName!Range` then you will get the string between the = and the ! placed into A2

> You cannot run these functions without supplying the event object. If you attempt to run from the script editor without supplying the event object you will get an error.  The onEdit trigger is a simple trigger meaning that it cannot perform functions that require permission.  If you need tp perform commands that require permission you must create an installable trigger either programmatically or through the editors trigger panel.

There are several limitations running scripts this way.  You will have difficulty using alert and prompt boxes.  They are fairly difficult to debug because the onEdit is not easily run in debug mode so you are left having to edit the appropriate elements on the desired sheet."